How to make sure the positive semidefinite matrix?
How to identity the following matrix $A=\left(\begin{array} xx&y\\y&z\end{array}\right)$is semidefinite when $x\ge0,z\ge 0,xz\ge y^2$ by using any vector $\textbf{z}$, $\textbf{z}^TA\textbf{z}\ge0$?
I tried $\textbf{z}=\left(\begin{array} aa_1\\a_2\end{array}\right)$ and get $a_1^2x+2a_1a_2y+a_2^2z\ge0$, and let $x\ge0, z\ge0$, but how to obtain $xz\ge y^2$ without using the det? I have seen one proof on the stackexchange but it is wrong definitely and I do not wanna use Schur complement.

Where is that wrong proof?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183078/how-can-i-derive-the-conditions-of-positive-semidefinite-cone-in-2-times2-matr

Consider this quadratic equation $a_1^2x+2a_1a_2y+a_2^2z\ge0$, where a's are the variables, x,y,z are the coefficients

Thanks! Let the $f(a_1)=xa_1^2+2a_2ya_1+a_2^2z$, and consider the relation between discriminant and $f(a_1)\ge0$, and I think I have finshed the proof!

You need the quadratic inequality always true, as it holds for any vectors $\bf{z}$. Therefore, its quadratic function cannot have distinct real roots, so its discriminant is nonnegative. In another words $$(2y)^2-4(x)(z)\le 0$$
As a remark, $x\ge0$ and $z\ge0$ can also be derived in the same way because otherwise the first will lead to the quadratic function graph is open downwrads, and the second one will make the inequality fails at $\textbf{z}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}.$

Right. Or, we think x,z are kind of symmetric, both coefficients should be nonnegative to make sure the corresponding quadratic function curves upwards.

Thanks! Maybe $z\ge0$ can be derived by letting the polynomial as the quadratic function of a2 whose graph demands upwards like what we have discussed in $x\ge0$.
